# JSR223 Jmeter. Написание запроса на groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

Добрый день господа форумчане.
Прошу помочь со следующей проблемой

нужно с помощью JRS223 на языке groovy распарсить html(Возможно xml) index(главной страницы любого сайты) и вывести в debug список найденных элементов (среди элементов title и все ссылки).
Регулярка для запросов имеется: <title>(.*?)</title>|<a href="(.*?)"

Структура кейса пока-что выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отличный скриншот, Кирилл, но вообще-то [это не сервис, где люди пишут для вас вместо вас код](https://sopython.com/wiki/Useful_Comments#code-service)

Так что на будущее лучше показывайте что внутри JSR223 PostProcessor и лучше не в виде скриншота, а в виде кода

В виде исключения держите примерную имплементацию:

```
(prev.getResponseDataAsString() =~ /<title>(.*?)<\/title>|<a href="(.*?)"/).each { match ->
    log.info(match as String)
}
```

И результат ее работы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- `prev` - результат выполнения предыдущего Sampler, документация по всем функциям - [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
- `log` - [Log4JLogger](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.html)

Больше информации на тему всех этих `prev`, `log`, `ctx`, `vars`, `props` - [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)